# Unable To Connect To FZS

Tags: filezilla

Everything was working perfectly, but this morning, now all of a sudden I am unable to connect to my Filezilla Server.  I am within my network, so I am connecting to an IP address.  But it just keeps on showing

> Status:   Connecting to XXX.XXX.5.XXX:990... Error:   Connection timed out
>   after 20 seconds of inactivity Error: Could not connect to server
>   Status:   Waiting to retry... Status: Connecting to XXX.XXX.5.XXX:990...
>   Error:    Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
>   Error:    Could not connect to server

**EDIT**
Windows Firewall is disabled on both PC's.  I just disabled MSE on 1 PC that had it running to rule out that is the issue and no luckk.

I can connect no problem from outside of my network, inside my LAN is where the issue lies.

Yes, I have verified it is the correct port, username and password.

**EDIT #2**
After a fresh reboot of both PC's, I am still unable to connect.  If I open command prompt and try to ping the Server LAN IP all 4 packets are lost.

I can use Team Viewer and VNC the Server PC no problem and everything seems to be up and running as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right port? Are you using Implicit TLS?